# Rest and/or Node.JS API to get Bitcoin (BTC) and/or Etherium (ETH) global metadata

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, bitcoin, cryptocurrency, bitcore

Is there a REST or Node.JS library API that provides global network metadata for Bitcoin and/or Etherum ?

The metadata I'm looking for is -

- Average wait time for a transaction confirmation on the network
- Average fee cost per transaction on the network

I know I could crawl/parse one of the many sites that provide this data, but that's not ideal. Hence I'm looking for a dedicated API to obtain this information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eventually I found out of places like [CryptoCompare](https://www.cryptocompare.com/) that provide that data